Confusion for algorithm for finding (a div d) and (a mod d), where a is an integer and d positive integer.


From Rosen's discrete Math textbook. I'm confused on 3 things regarding this algorithm (as can be seen via the screenshots)

Why do we need an algorithm for finding $a$ div $d$ and $a$ mod $d$ when we know they simply equal $\lfloor\frac{a}{d}\rfloor$ and $(a - d\lfloor\frac{a}{d}\rfloor)$, respectively.
I feel this algorithm doesn't work for the case when $a < 0$ and $r = 0$. Kindly could someone please help confirm/explain.
How do we prove that the algorithm works for the other 3 cases ($a \geq 0$ and $r = 0$; $a > 0$ and $0 < r < d$; or $a < 0$ and $0 < r < d$)? This algorithm seem to work for these cases intuitively, but I'm not sure how to go about proving this in a mathematically rigorous/sufficient fashion.

Kindly please help me understand this algorithm better.

The loop terminates with $,|a| = qd+r,\ 0\le r<d.,$ If $,a<0,$ and $,r>0,$ it negates this equation to $,-|a| = -(q+1)d + d-r.,$ What is not clear about that?  This is a duplicate. $\ \ $

"Why do you need an algorithm when it's simply $\lfloor \frac{a}{d}\rfloor$"? So you think that people that program computers just tell the computer: "compute $\lfloor \frac{a}{d}\rfloor$" ?

The not clear part is question 2, when the while loop terminates with $a<0$ and $r=0$. Still $\lvert a\rvert = qd+r$, but $(q,r)$ does not get adjusted, so for the return value $a \ne qd + r\quad (= \lvert a \rvert = -a)$.

"Why do we need an algorithm for finding a div d and a mod d when we know they simply equal ⌊ad⌋ and (a−d⌊ad⌋), respectively."  The algorithm is nothing more nor less than how we calculate them and how we know the have values in the first place..  This is akin so asking  Why to we need an algorithm to sovle $x + 5 = 12$ when we know it is just $12-5$.  $x+5=12$ is the very definition of $12-5$ and the algorithm is how we know we define division and remainder in the first place.

Yes, you are right that it doesn't work for $a < 0$ and $r=0$.  If should be "IF (a<0) THEN (IF r > 0 THEN r=d-r; q=-(q+1) ELSE q=-q)"

"How do we prove that the algorithm works for the other 3 cases (a≥0 and r=0; a>0 and 0<r<d; or a<0 and 0<r<d)?"  Those are all right there.  They work exactly as it says.

if $a<0$ and $r>0$ then return $(-(q+1), d-r)$; if $a<0$ and $r=0$ then return $(-q, r)$; return $(q, r)$

@fleablood '"How do we prove that the algorithm works for the other 3 cases (a≥0 and r=0; a>0 and 0<r<d; or a<0 and 0<r<d)?" Those are all right there. They work exactly as it says' ... sorry I'm not following. Kindly could you please elaborate in an answer?

@fleablood "The algorithm is nothing more nor less than how we calculate them and how we know the have values in the first place.." Are you saying basically that $\lfloor\frac{a}{d}\rfloor$ is calculated via this algorithm by our calculators and computer? Kindly if you could also elaborate this in an answer I'd be grateful.

I have no idea how computers and calculators compute $\lfloor \frac ad\rfloor$.  I'm saying WE do it that way.   The entire meaning of "a divided by d" is concept that "if we keep looking at multiples of $d$ we must eventually find one the is as close to $a$ as we can get without going over".  That's the definition of $a\div d$, that's the concept, and that's the algorithm.  THey are all exactly the same thing.

Some observations for the proof: 1) Before and after every iteration of the while loop, $\lvert a\rvert = qd+r$. After every iteration, $r\ge 0$. 2) The while loop terminates, because there exists integer $q'$ that makes $\lvert a\rvert < q'd + d$ (some consequent of the Archimedean property and $d>0$). 3) If $a\ge 0$ i.e. $a=\lvert a\rvert$, the algorithm returns such $(q,r)$. If $a<0$ and $r>0$, the adjustment follows what @BillDubuque wrote.

@peterwhy It terminates (with $,0\le r < d)$ since otherwise the sequence of values of $,r,$ would be an infinite decreasing sequence of naturals, contra $\Bbb N$ is well-ordered. $,qd+r$ is indeed a loop invariant since subtracting $d$ from $r$ is balanced by adding $1$ to $q,,$ i.e. $,qd+r = (q!+!1)d+r!-!d\ \ $
